# Swift - Model unit testing with ObjectMapper

Tags: xcode, swift, unit-testing, model, xctest

I have a bunch of models using the ObjectMapper library (as I'm parsing JSON to build the objects).
How can I write unit tests for my models? I'm fairly new to this and have been pretty confused by what I've read so far.
Here's an example of one of my models:

```
import ObjectMapper

class User: Mappable {
    var id: Int?
    var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?

    required init?(_ map: Map) {
        mapping(map)
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        id        <- map["ID"]
        firstName <- map["first_name"]
        lastName  <- map["last_name"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Maybe try this:

```
import XCTest
import ObjectMapper
@testable import AppName

class User Tests: XCTestCase {

    func testMapsData() {
        let jsonDictionary: [String: Any] = ["id": 10, "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe"]
        let user = Mapper<User>().map(JSON: jsonDictionary)

        XCTAssertEqual(user?.id, 10)
        XCTAssertEqual(user?.firstName, "John")
        XCTAssertEqual(user?.lastName, "Doe")
    }

}
```